# How to stop Android GPS using "Mobile data"

Tags: android, gps

My app requests location updates with "minTime" set to 2 seconds. When "Mobile data" is switched on (in the phone's settings) and GPS is enabled the app uses "mobile data" at between 5 and 10 megabytes per hour. This is recorded in the ICS "Data usage" screen as usage by "Android OS".

In an attempt to prevent this I have unticked Settings->"Location services"->"Google's location service". Does this refer to Assisted GPS, or is it something more than that? Whatever it is, it seems to make no difference to my app's internet access.

As further confirmation that it is the GPS usage by my app that is causing the mobile data access I have observed that the internet data activity indicator on the status bar shows activity when and only when the GPS indicator is present.

The only way to prevent this mobile data usage seems to be to switch "Mobile data" off, and GPS accuracy seems to be almost as good without the support of mobile data. However, it is obviously unsatisfactory to have to switch mobile data off.

The only permissions in the Manifest are "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" (and "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"), so the app has no explicit permission to use internet data.

The LocationManager code is

```
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
     
    bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    if (bestProvider != null) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, gpsMinTime, gpsMinDistance, this);
```

The [reference for LocationManager.getBestProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29) says

> If no provider meets the criteria, the criteria are loosened ... Note that the requirement on monetary cost is not removed in this process.

However, despite setting setCostAllowed to false the app still incurs a potential monetary cost.

What else can I do to prevent the app from using mobile data?

Comment: "Google's location service" is not A-GPS.  It is the location database they have based on the collected WIFI ssids and such.  A-GPS can't be turned off as it is core to Android.  Some custom firmwares such as Samsung might allow this but AOSP does not.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What does setCostAllowed(false) do of it doesn't prevent the location manager from using internet data?

Comment: Hmm good point.  I had no idea about this setCostAllowed thing.  maybe someone with more android knowledge can dive into the Android code and see what this does exactly.

Comment: I wonder whether the problem might be that setCostAllowed is implemented in different ways on different devices, and perhaps on my phone (Galaxy Note) it is not working in the way I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

the network provider usually includes all kinds of non-gps positioning techniques , such as AGPS , wifi and cell triangulation , or any combination of them . on some devices they are separated . you can also add passive provider , which uses locations stored on other apps .

anyway , if you don't wish to use the internet/3g , you need to disable this feature , either in the app or by the end user.

for the end user , this feature is turned off by default , and if he chooses to enable it , he is warned about it (as opposed to iphone which has it enabled by default) .

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I disable location manager internet access in the app?

Comment: you mean you wish to disable the settings that the user has specifically requested to be enabled ? how about simply tell the user that the app is using it on the app's description ? if he didn't enable it, use the gps instead . gps is more accurate , but it takes more battery .

Comment: I don't seem to have explained myself very clearly. Of course the user should determine whether the phone's mobile data access is switched on. However, my problem is that an app that uses GPS but has no explicit permission to access the internet is in fact using many megabytes of internet data. I think many users would be surprised by this, and potentially rather cross. I certainly would be.
As discussed above, one of the issues is that Google have provided a setCostAllowed setting for LocationManager, but it is not obvious how it works (or whether it can be relied on to work at all).